# Global character array won't be reassigned or outputted correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, char, global

I'm trying to make a very basic tic tac toe program, and I'm storing the board in a character array. The array is global so I can output it from a function and also assign X's and O's to places in the main function. My code is below. The problem is it won't compile correctly. If I add char before I reassign it in main, it compiles but does not run correctly. My C++ teacher is confused too, so I thought I'd ask here.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "charconvert.h"
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
char board[3][3] =
{
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' }
};
void boardout();
int main()
{
    int currentplayer = 1;
    char p1 = 'X';
    char p2 = 'O';
    char pactive;
    int rounds = 1;
    board[3][3] = {
        { '1', '2', '3' },
        { '4', '5', '6' },
        { '7', '8', '9' }
    };
    boardout();
    bool gameover = false;
    do
    {
        if (rounds % 2 == 0){ currentplayer = 1; }
        if (rounds % 2 != 0){ currentplayer = 2; }
        boardout();
        chartoint input;
        char playermove;
        do
        {
            cout << "Player " << currentplayer << ", what space will you go on?" << endl;
            cin >> playermove;
        } while (!isdigit(playermove));
        int space = input.convert(playermove);
        if (currentplayer == 1){ pactive = p1; }
        if (currentplayer == 2){ pactive = p2; }
        if (!(space>9) && !(space<0))
        {
            switch (space)
            {
            case 1:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[0][0] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[1][0] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[2][0] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[0][1] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[1][1] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[2][1] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[0][2] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 8:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[1][2] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            case 9:
                if (space == ' ')
                {
                    board[2][2] = pactive;
                }
                else{ cout << "That space is already used. You forfeit this turn." << endl; }
                break;
            default:
                cout << "That is an invalid space. You forfeit your turn." << endl;
            }
        }
        char yn;
        cout << "Is the game over? Enter Y for yes or N for no." << endl;
        cin >> yn;
        if (yn == 'Y' || yn == 'y'){ gameover = true; }
        rounds++;
    } while (!gameover);
    return 0;
}
void boardout()
{
    int x, y;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << board[x][y];
            if (x != 2){ cout << " | "; }
            x++;
        } while (x <= 2);
        if (y != 2)
        {
            cout << "\n---------" << endl;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    } while (y <= 2);
}
```

Here's charconvert.h:

```
#ifndef CHARCONVERT_H_INCLUDED
#define CHARCONVERT_H_INCLUDED
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class chartoint
{
public:
int convert(char);
};

int chartoint::convert(char in)
{
int out = in;
out = out - 48;
return out;
}

class strtonum
{
public:
int strconvert(string);
};

int strtonum::strconvert(string input)
{
int numdigs = input.size();
//cout << input << endl;
//cout << "int numdigs = input.size();\nnumdigs = " << numdigs << endl;
int c=0;
//cout << "int c=0;" << endl;
 int number [numdigs];
//cout << "int number [10] = { };\n";
/*int n=0;
do
{
    cout << "number [" << n << "] = " << number[n] << endl;
    n++;
}
while(n<11);*/
int output = 0;
char tempnumc;
int tempnumi;
//int tenminusc = 10 - c;
if(numdigs<=10)
{
    //cout << "entered if(numdigs<=10)" << endl;
    do
    {
    //cout << "c = " << c << endl;
    tempnumc = input[c];
    //cout << "temp char " << tempnumc << endl;
    tempnumi = tempnumc;
    //cout << "temp i " << tempnumi << endl;
    tempnumi = tempnumi - 48;
    //cout << "temp i " << tempnumi << endl;
    number[c] = tempnumi;
    //cout << "number 10 - c = " << number[tenminusc] << endl;
    //cout << "input[numdigs-c] = number[10-c];" << endl << "numdigs-c = " << numdigs-c << '\t'<< "input[numdigs-c] = " << input[numdigs-c] << '\t' << "number[10-c] = " << number[10-c] << endl;
    //cout << "output = " << output << endl;
    int idontevenknowatthispoint;
    idontevenknowatthispoint = (numdigs-c)-1;
    output = output + (number[c]*pow(10,idontevenknowatthispoint));
    //cout << "output = output + (number[10-c]*pow(10,c));" << endl;
    //cout << "pow(10,c) = " << pow(10,c) << endl;
    //cout << "(number[c]*pow(10,c) = " << number[c]*pow(10,idontevenknowatthispoint) << endl;
    c++;
    tempnumc = ' ';
    tempnumi = 0;
    }
    while(c < numdigs);
    if(numdigs==3)
    {
        output = output + 1;
    }
    if(numdigs==9)
    {
        output = output + 2;
    }
}
else
{
    output = -42;
}
return output;
}

#endif // CHARCONVERT_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Can you give us your `charconvert.h` so we can test your application?

Comment: Well, what is the compiler error, and where??

Comment: The error is "Line 23: error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'char' in assignment|"

Comment: "It won't compile correctly" "It won't run correctly" These are vastly too vague problem statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reassign an array like:

```
board[3][3] = {
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' }
};
```

Since you never use board before you try to assign values to it in `main()` just replace

```
char board[3][3] =
{
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' }
};
```

With

```
char board[3][3] = 
{
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' }
};
```

If you do not want to have the global array populated with the numbers at the start of the program then you would need to set each individual array element with the value you want.  You could do that with a couple for loops:

```
for (int i = 0, spot = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        board[i][j] = spot + '0';
        spot++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did that, and it runs, but I want to replace the numbers with spaces when they start playing. If the way I assigned it before was wrong, what would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: @DanFiscus I edited my post.  see the last part to see how to change the contents of the array from spaces to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the char array "board" twice - once globally (outside any function) and again in main(). You only need to declare it once (globally), and I would add the word "static" at the start of the declaration line (recommended practice).

If you declare "board" in main(), then you have to pass it to the lower-level functions as a pointer (and as a pointer to a pointer using '&' if you want to change the array). Here is a web site reference showing how to allocate and pass a copy of a string to another function (the called function cannot change the string):
https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/
and
http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html

If you need more help, see me offline.
Tom Durand
tmdurand@gci.net

Comment: There is only one array declaration.  The line in `main()` is a reassignment not a re-declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reinitialize the board array again in the main function. You can only use the initializer when you declare it. It should also probably be declared as static. If you want to modify it in main() then you need to reference the individual cells and give them a value.